# What is the difference between Operative and Operational?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What is the difference between Operative and Operational?

Research shows no other such question https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=operational+operative.

Comment: Can you perhaps give some examples? Meaning is usually determined by context, so a few example sentences with each word would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

An operative is a person who is skilled at doing something. (Someone who takes part in an operation)
When something is operational, it can be operated (it works) (operational=functional)

Comment: But something can also be said to be _operative_ (or, more commonly, _inoperative_).

Comment: When something is operative, it is in use. Ιt can also mean that something is valid (an agreement for example)